# Path must include project and resource name: /.gitignore

Tags: java, git, eclipse, egit, sts

i just use sts 4.9.0

The problem is this: whenever I do almost anything
(ex. save a file I'm working on)

I get an error:

`An error has occurred. See error log for more details. Path must include project and resource name: /.gitignore`

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /.gitignore
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2128)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFile(Container.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingViewContentProvider.getFile(StagingViewContentProvider.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingEntry.getFile(StagingEntry.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingEntry.getProblemSeverity(StagingEntry.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.ProblemLabelDecorator.decorateImage(ProblemLabelDecorator.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingLabelProvider.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider.updateLabel(DecoratingLabelProvider.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView$TreeDecoratingLabelProvider.updateLabel(StagingView.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.WrappedViewerLabelProvider.update(WrappedViewerLabelProvider.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:959)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2111)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1599)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalInitializeTree(TreeViewer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$1(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1400)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1361)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView.setStagingViewerInput(StagingView.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView.lambda$19(StagingView.java:3907)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.staging.StagingView$56.runInUIThread(StagingView.java:4542)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4001)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3629)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
```

and Session Data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.9.0.202012132054
java.version=15.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ko_KR
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
```

i did Maven > update Project to all my projects

but it's still the same situation

And I used it well before without this error

It happened when i formatted the computer and cloned the this repositoris again

and it already exist .gitignore file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkk8d.png

i can't find out how to fix it

i hope it will fix it!

Thanks

Comment: The error log is in the eclipse error window. also does not seems like a error related to git itself.

Comment: i edit my post! Could you check out this again? @Popeye

Comment: I think, Java project property missing project name and resource path. Is your project a maven/gradle project? if not, consider that. Also restart your eclipse. clean exit and then start, also consider to delete the build file under target directory and rebuild the project.

Comment: it's maven .. i should delete it and clone it again  Thank you for your answer

Comment: Why is there a `.metadata` folder in the working tree of your Git repository? This does not look correct.

Comment: OMG. you are totally right. i checked other projects. there are no `.metadata` folder! Thanks a lot. i'll delete and create again my git repository @howlger